# Parse json and unable to access javascript object

Tags: json, gson

I am passing a json object to the client side from java object with a time and value as attributes with gson

`this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/123", gson.toJson(object, type));`

and on the client side i have the following code where the json object data is stored in the body of the payload but I am unable to access the properties with obj.time or obj.value, it tells me undefined after it is parsed, I tried showing the entire 'obj' itself and the format seems fine however:

```
var subscription_callback1 = function(payload) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(payload.body);
        alert(obj);
};
```

output with alert(obj)

`{"time":"3:00:34","value":"7989797"}`

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind solved. Since I am transfering STOMP protocol messages with the Spring 4 framework. I opted to use the Jackson2 message converter instead of directly using gson and it seems to work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MessageBrokerConfigurer extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    return true;
}
```

then i directly put my java object into the send function instead of using gson to convert it as above

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/123", event)
```